# $A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix such that $\mbox{ Tr }(A-A^t)^{2n}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

If $A\in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix such that $\mbox{ Tr }(A-A^t)^{2n}=0$ for some integer $n>0$. Show that $A=A^t$

I have tried like this: Let $X=A-A^t$. Then $X$ is a skew symmetric matrix with all its eigenvalues are zero. This follows from the trace condition. From this how I can proceed?

Comment: Technically, $X$ doesn't have sum of all its eigenvalues zero. There is an $n>0$ such that $X^{2n}$ has sum of all its eigenvalues zero.

Comment: Tr $X$=0, this is because Tr $X$=Tr$ A$- Tr$ A^t$=0

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly worded. What I meant was that that isn't what the trace condition tells you. In _any_ skew-symmetric matrix, all diagonal entries are $0$, so the trace is $0$. It's not the given trace condition which tells you this.

Comment: Using the given trace condition we can conclude that all the eigenvalues of X=A-$A^t$ will be zero. This follows from the fact that all eigenvalues of a skew symmetric matrix are either 0 or purely imaginary. Now from the given trace condition we obtain that all eigenvalues of X is zero. from this it is enough to show that X=0. But how to show this.

Comment: I can get that $X^2 = 0$ (all complex eigenvalues being $0$ means it's nilpotent and $X^2$ being symmetric means it's diagonalizable, and there is only one nilpotent diagonalizable matrix). But I don't see yet how to get $X = 0$ from that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the number-crunching route: Show that for $n>1$ and an arbitrary skew-symmetric matrix, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&a&b\\-a&0&c\\-b&-c&0
\end{bmatrix}^{2n} = (-1)^n(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}a^2 + b^2 & bc&-ac\\bc & a^2 + c^2 & ab\\-ac&ab&b^2+c^2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$X=A-A^t$, being a $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric real matrix, have eigenvalues $0,\pm ic$ for some $c\geq 0$.  So $\operatorname{Tr} X^{2n}=2(-1)^nc^{2n}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=A-A^t$. Note that $X$ is a skew symmetric matrix. Now $X$ being a $3\times3$ skew symmetric real matrix, its eigenvalues are $0,\pm i c$ for some $c\geq0$. Then $$\mbox{ Tr }X^{2n}=0\implies2(-1)^{n}c^{2n}=0\implies c=0$$ Hence all the eigenvalues of $X$ are zero. Now consider $$\mbox{ Tr }(XX^t)=\mbox{ Tr }(X(-X))=-\mbox{ Tr }X^2=0.$$ Consequently we have $X=0\implies A=A^t.$